# Under what circumstances would 5V@2.1A be lethal?

Tags: voltage, resistance

Besides obviously sticking an output of 5V directly to the heart. Are there areas inside the body where resistance in ohms is so low that a 5V electric potential would be fatal?

I got into an argument about this with my roommate after he made a joke about sticking an lightning apple lightning cable directly up his urethra. I told him that his brilliant idea could  cause a nasty shock since internal body resistance is so low. He, however, insisted that the lowest internal body resistance still sits at a few hundred ohms and 5V (5V 2.1A Charger) would not suffice to provide a dangerous current.

Would it be possible for internal resistance in this area to be so low that even 5V or less would be dangerous? Say it took a path up the bladder and through the kidneys and to the heart.

Comment: Sounds like medical college grad joke. If you have multimeter, propose him to measure the resistance in his urethra. Not sure where second probe will go  though. Depends on the area of medicine he is studying.

Comment: Plausible: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39869/killed-by-9v-battery-via-multimeter

Comment: Ha ha. This really made my morning.  :-)  Since the + and - terminals will be very close together, I doubt that the current will travel all the way to the heart. It might result in a shock or tinkling sensation in the urethra area.

Comment: If you lick on 5V, you will feel it for sure, but not more than that.

Comment: Somewhat related to https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39869/killed-by-9v-battery-via-multimeter

Comment: don't do this. I mean, don't stick *any* part of *any* electrical appliance up your urethra. stuff like this will a) upset the HNQ again, b) fuel the Darwin Awards and c) have us end up with the obligation to ship devices with new hazard signs depicting prohibited uses noone wants to see.

Comment: I think the biggest dangers from a 5v @2.1 amp power supply would be 1) somehow starting a fire with it and allowing fire to go out of control, or 2) someone throwing the PS very hard at your head.  Otherwise the 115  (or 220 ) vAC outlets all over your house are far more dangerous.

Comment: "5V@2.1A" May not mean what you think it means.  If you see it on a wall-wart power supply, then the "5V" part _usually_ means that the supply will try to maintain 5V, and the current will be controlled by whatever is connected to it.  The "2.1A" usually means, that if the device tries to take _more_ than 2.1A, then the power supply will fail to live up to its end of the bargain, and something else will happen.  There's a range of possible something-elses, which cover the space between the power supply gracefully shutting down at one end, and it belching smoke and fire at the other.

Comment: Re, "...a path up the bladder and through the kidneys..." Electricity in the body is not constrained to follow the same pathways as body fluids.  As far as electricity is concerned, your entire body is just one big bag of salt water.

Answer (score 14):

if applied for a long duration electrolysis can cause acid/alkali burns - see warnings about swallowed lithium button cells.

Comment: You're right, but the question seems to be more about a charger than battery cells. Surely eating a 5V charger would also lead to some injuries, though.

Comment: Lookup videos of button cell batteries inside sausages. This is what kills kids when they swallow them.

Comment: @dim yeah it's not the same, but a 5V 2A supply is stronger than a CR2032, the voltage is higher and the available current is greater, there is more potential for fatal injury

Answer (score 12):

Except if you proceed with a surgery to apply the 5V directly on the heart, or some other vital organ, it certainly can't be lethal.

The resistance between any two accessible points on your body is either:

- Rather low, because the two points are very close together, possibly on a wet surface (e.g. the tongue... or the urethra, whatever...). So a significant current goes through, and you can feel it (it could hurt), but it won't kill you because the current will not disturb or harm any vital organ because they aren't in its way.
- Very high, because the two points are far away from each other, in which case the current will be so low you probably won't even notice.

The NIOSH states "Under dry conditions, the resistance offered by the human body may be as high as 100,000 ohms. Wet or broken skin may drop the body's resistance to 1,000 ohms". "Wet or broken skin" could be the equivalent of what you have on the tongue (urethra?), so at 5V it would give 5mA. Which apparently translates to "perceptible but no muscle reaction".

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_injury

Comment: '"Wet or broken skin" could be the equivalent of what you have on the tongue (urethra?)' - But the tongue, and the inside of the urethra, aren't covered by any skin at all. It seems dangerous to generalize from "wet or broken skin" to "no skin".

Comment: @Tanner I assumed "broken skin" means "no skin at that location". I may be wrong, but anyway, if you choose these locations (tongue/urethra), you'll end up in the case where there is no vital organ in the way... Well, now that I think about it, maybe not... If you put one pole on the tongue and the other in the urethra. At that point, I don't know. And I don't want to try.

Comment: Would you mind to change the wording of "current takes the path of least resistance" because it's wrong?

Comment: @Jasper Indeed. But honestly, I don't know how to state "current takes all paths, in 1/R proportion, so the least resistance path will take most of the current, and longer paths will take very little in proportion, because their resistance are magnitudes higher" in an intelligible way without confusing everybody. Feel free to edit if you think of a good way to state that with a few words that don't get in the way of the rest of the statement.

Comment: I tried........

Answer (score 5):

He may feel a localised electric shock, with 5V stimulating sensitive areas.  The two electrodes for the 5V supply are both within the cable though, so current will only pass through a very small portion of his urethral area.  It certainly will not reach his heart, unless he breaks the cable open and pierces his skin with a connector.

On another note, I have friends who engage in putting things up their urethra.  (It's known as "urethral sounds".)  Whether adding 5V would cause significantly more pain than the already-painful act of sticking a cable up there, I couldn't say, but simply stuffing something up there is definitely not comfortable.  (Which is why they do it, of course.)

The average USB cable is relatively large, compared to the urethral hole.  I assume he's planning on cutting the connector off, because that simply would not fit up there without causing damage.  Even with the connector cut off though, a cable that size is likely to cause some injury for someone who is not used to this.  Also the cut-off end of the cable will be rough and will likely also cause damage - there's a reason that people who do this use medical equipment, which is made of smooth, rounded metal.  The risk of infection is therefore also very high.

At best, your friend is in for some serious discomfort.  More likely, your friend is on his way to hospital, and thereby to infamy via hospital war story.  At worst, Mr Happy may be permanently damaged, and your friend will never pee normally or have sex again.

Not recommended.

Comment: [TMI](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/too_much_information)

Comment: I learnt something new today :) interesting to see what people do with themselves and how it is called

Comment: @pipe You read that the question, saw that it involved the OP's friend sticking a USB cable up their knob, and you ***still*** scrolled down to read answers?  I'd say you opted in on this information. ;)

Comment: @Anonymous On my side, I could have lived without this information. I can feel pain just by thinking about it.

Comment: @dim humor apart, you may be surprised how many people you know may be of this kind. They all have urethra, and this question should be viral as everyone has phone charger these days. If you recall putting light bulb into the mouth. As a curious and responsible person, I would like to learn on the motives and first aid for stranger doing something like this! If I would not be an engineer, I would be a doctor (well, doctor is the one engineering human beings - so we all are a kind of doctors here).

Comment: @Anonymous I doubt you'll need to learn how to administer first aid for something like this.  It's not immediately life-threatening.  The "viral" advice would be that Rule 34 applies - if you can imagine it, there's porn of it, or at least someone is doing it because they *really* enjoy it.  And based on that, the chances are pretty good that kink groups will be able to give advice on how to do it sensibly and safely.  (Whilst some kind of injury is frequently involved in kink, you do want to minimise the risk of *accidental* injury.)  So inform yourself of the risks before doing it.